# Error creating bean with name 'worklight-direct'

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using the MobileFirst Platform on Liberty profile and DB2 for database.

I deployed the new project war file on the Mobile First Platform. after the deployment I restart the server when I try to access the Mobile First Platform console I am getting the below error.

but the project schema, Mobile First Platform schema and report schema are there and currently there has not been any change on DB2 side.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>       creating bean with name 'worklight-direct' defined in URL
>       [wsjar:file:/appl/was1/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/hamfactoryapps/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]:
>       Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLSE0206E: The project /hamfactoryapps failed
>       to initialize, because the project database schema for data source
>       jdbc:db2://xxxxxx:51000/WRKLGHT is from version N/A,
>       which is not supported by the server from version 6.3.0.00.20141127-1357.
>       Use the MobileFirst ant tasks to upgrade the project database schema.
>       [project hamfactoryapps]
>              at
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean
>       (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>              at
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean
>       (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
>              at
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
>       $1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)

I delete the old schema and I create the new one, after I'm getting the below error.

[ERROR   ] CWNEN0030E: The @Resource factory encountered a problem getting the object instance jdbc/WorklightAdminDS binding object.  The exception message was: failed to resolve jdbc/WorklightAdminDS to javax.sql.DataSource
[WARNING ] Expected an object of type DataSource, but found: null
[ERROR   ] Context initialization failed
Error creating bean with name 'registrationServiceFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-management-service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open data base. DataStoreFactory returned null for unknown reason.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationServiceFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-management-service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open data base. DataStoreFactory returned null for unknown reason.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your database schema as the exception states: `The project /hamfactoryapps failed to initialize, because the project database schema for data source jdbc:db2://xxxxxx:51000/WRKLGHT is from version N/A, which is not supported by the server from version 6.3.0.00.20141127-1357`

Comment: Edit the question and detail all the steps, step by step that you've followed. You made a mistake somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 0):

This error would happen if you are trying to access the wrong schema than the one you have intended to use. Double-check this.

Also make sure that you have used the correct create-worklight-db2.sql. See the documentation here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/devref/t_ant_tasks_configure_dbs_wlconsole.html

purge the database and re-create it based on the above.

Comment: Thank Ldan Adar, I am going to drop the schema's and recreate them, I will point the new schema on Server.xml. I hope this will resolve the problem.